# SQL Server group by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT [DATE], [AMOUNT], SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS 'Running Total' 
FROM PeopleActi
WHERE INSTANCE = 'Bank' 
AND DATE IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY [DATE], [AMOUNT];
```

In the code above I selecting a user's date, amount and the `"SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS 'Running Total'"` is the running total of their costs over a period of dates. When I run this code I get the following results:

```
DATE       AMOUNT  Running Total
2018-10-05  100     100
2018-10-06  1000    1100
2018-10-07  5000    6100
2018-10-08  2000    8100
2018-10-09  1000    9100
2018-10-10  5000    14100
2018-10-11  3000    25100
2018-10-11  8000    25100
```

This works nicely but my issue is the last two rows. I wanted them to be grouped by their date and have the total amount for both same days, so it should be:

```
 Date       Amount   Running Total
2018-10-11   11000    25100
```

Does anyone have an idea of how this can achieved? My `[DATE]` is of type DATE.

UPDATE!!!!

I've seen some of your solutions and they are good but its important I display the AMOUNT and the Running Total amount as well, so the final result should be...

```
DATE       AMOUNT  Running Total
2018-10-05  100     100
2018-10-06  1000    1100
2018-10-07  5000    6100
2018-10-08  2000    8100
2018-10-09  1000    9100
2018-10-10  5000    14100
2018-10-11  11000   25100
```

Thank you everyone for the help so far!

Comment: Then, only group by `Date`.

Comment: Don't group by amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Subselect:

```
SELECT p.[DATE], p.[AMOUNT], SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS 'Running Total' 
FROM 
(
    select [date], sum([amount]) as Amount from PeopleActi
    WHERE INSTANCE = 'Bank' 
    AND DATE IS NOT NULL
    group by [date]
) p
GROUP BY p.[DATE], p.[AMOUNT]
```

Comment: This is veru close but could you include the "WHERE INSTANCE = 'Bank' " as well???

Answer (score 2):

Group up the amounts and then do your cumulative total

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  A.Dt,
            SUM(A.Amount) AS Amount
    FROM    (
                VALUES  ('2018-10-05',100),
                        ('2018-10-06',1000),
                        ('2018-10-07',5000),
                        ('2018-10-08',2000),
                        ('2018-10-09',1000),
                        ('2018-10-10',5000),
                        ('2018-10-11',3000),
                        ('2018-10-11',8000)
            ) AS A(Dt,Amount)
    GROUP   BY A.Dt
)
SELECT  C.Dt,
        C.Amount,
        SUM(C.Amount) OVER (ORDER BY C.Dt) AS CumTotal
FROM    CTE AS C;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

```
SELECT [DATE],sum( [AMOUNT]), SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS 'Running Total' 
FROM PeopleActi
WHERE INSTANCE = 'Bank' 
AND DATE IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY [DATE]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need groping sum then why you are using window function, only aggregation is enough :

```
SELECT [DATE], SUM([AMOUNT])
FROM PeopleActi
WHERE INSTANCE = 'Bank' AND DATE IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY [DATE];
```

Answer (score 1):

Every field in a group by is going to cause it to potentially create new lines. If you SUM the amount field and remove it from your grouping, that should solve the issue. EDIT: I see the issue, I provided a fully stand alone example of the query below that you can adapt.

```
DECLARE @PeopleActi TABLE ([DATE] DATE,[AMOUNT] MONEY)
INSERT INTO @PeopleActi SELECT '2018-10-05',100 
INSERT INTO @PeopleActi SELECT '2018-10-06',1000
INSERT INTO @PeopleActi SELECT '2018-10-07',5000
INSERT INTO @PeopleActi SELECT '2018-10-08',2000
INSERT INTO @PeopleActi SELECT '2018-10-09',1000
INSERT INTO @PeopleActi SELECT '2018-10-10',5000
INSERT INTO @PeopleActi SELECT '2018-10-11',3000
INSERT INTO @PeopleActi SELECT '2018-10-11',8000

SELECT *, SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS 'Running Total' 
FROM (
    SELECT [DATE], SUM([AMOUNT]) AS AMOUNT
    FROM @PeopleActi
    WHERE DATE IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY [DATE]
) a
GROUP BY [DATE],Amount
```

Comment: Unforunately this doesn't work, I'm getting the error

Column 'PeopleActi.AMOUNT' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Although I do believe your solution is the closest one! Have you tried testing this before?

Comment: @OverFlowMars Your error can't be exactly what came from the posted code because nothing is aliased "Input". We would really need the exact SQL you are using.

Comment: It is the same, I made a typo and corrected it now.

Comment: @OverFlowMars provided a stand alone version that shows how to do what you are wanting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH CTe([DATE],AMOUNT)
AS
(
SELECT '2018-10-05',  100   UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-10-06',  1000  UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-10-07',  5000  UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-10-08',  2000  UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-10-09',  1000  UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-10-10',  5000  UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-10-11',  3000  UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-10-11',  8000  
)
SELECT DISTINCT  [DATE],SUM(AMOUNT)OVER(PARTITION BY [DATE] ORDER BY [DATE]) AMOUNT , SUM(AMOUNT)OVER( ORDER BY [DATE]) AS RuningTot FROM CTe
```

Script

```
SELECT  DISTINCT [DATE], 
        SUM(AMOUNT)OVER(PARTITION BY [DATE] ORDER BY [DATE]) AS AMOUNT, 
        SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS 'Running Total' 
FROM PeopleActi
WHERE INSTANCE = 'Bank' 
AND DATE IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a CTE to first group by Date, and then do your running total ..
So something like

```
with myAmounts AS
(
SELECT [DATE], SUM([AMOUNT]) AS Amount 
FROM PeopleActi
WHERE INSTANCE = 'Bank' 
AND DATE IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY [DATE]
)
SELECT [DATE], [AMOUNT], SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS 'Running Total' 
FROM myAmounts

GROUP BY [DATE], [AMOUNT]
;
```

HTH,

B

ps; just saw that its the same answer as another .. democoding in action